# R - count of entries in a column , separated by ";"

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of entries in one specific column. Lets say we have a dataset /here represented by an matrix, like this

```
c=array(c(0,1,3,5,2,3,45,5,"Erk1","akt;Erk1","akt","NaN"), dim=c(4,3))
```

And now I would like to plot a barplot with the number of Erk1 - 2 akt -2, but I cannot get it.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `ios`?

Answer (score 2):

This will split the strings containing `;`:

```
dat <- unlist(strsplit(c[, 3], split = ";"))

#[1] "Erk1" "akt"  "Erk1" "akt"  "NaN"
```

The `table` function can be used to generate frequencies:

```
table(dat)

#dat
# akt Erk1 
#   2    2
```

This will generate the `barplot`:

```
barplot(table(dat))
```